# Passing PHP variable to Jquery without refresh

Tags: php, jquery

I apologize upfront for my lack of jquery knowledge. In this website I am building, a user is presented with a number of thumbnail images representing plants. When a thumbnail is clicked, a jquery popup is initiated. What I would like to be able to do is pass a php variable that has the ID of the plant over to the jquery popup to display the prper information. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: http://www.plantcombos.com/header/main_index.php?display=random_mix

Comment: can you post your html as well as jquery code. Or make a sample of you are trying to achieve at jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com

Comment: I would advise you post some code, or you will probably be voted down! We are here to help, not write for you!

Comment: To pass a PHP (server side) variable to Jquery (client side), you will need to make an AJAX call. Look at Jquery ajax (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Easy Ben, I'm not looking for anyone to write the code for me. I accidentally forgot to post the url

Comment: What he means is to post the relevant code in your question. Very few of us will want to navigate to another page, click to view source, and then try to find the relevant section.

Comment: @RyanBeaulieu Apologies for the outburst. There are a lot of people that come to Stackoverflow and show no appreciation for what the editors do, yet expect them to answer everything. Consider my +1 as an apology! :-) I have attempted to answer your question below. P.S. Site looks good!

Comment: No biggy Ben, I really do appreciate all the help. I realized as soon as I hit submit button that I forgot to post the url. From now on I will post my code instead of URL as well. I am very new to Stack Overflow so my apologies as well. Also, thank you for the help I am making the necessary tweaks now. Thanks again to you and everyone else who contributed and helped.

Comment: @RyanBeaulieu Completely understand, I am not exactly a Stackoverflow royal as I only joined a few months ago too. You will quickly learn the ropes though... :-) If you need any help with the answer I posted, just comment on it and I'll lend you a hand. Dont forget to include jQuery within your head tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the jQuery AJAX method to gather data from a PHP file and display it on the page. It is very easy and you can pass any variables (parameters) you like to the page.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

For example:

```
// This will send a request to a PHP page
$.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/test.php",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data){
        // Place the returned data into your content
        $('#image').html(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure you dont need to query PHP each time ... something like this would work :

```
<img class-"imgclick" src="/small-plant.jpg" data-id="123" />
```

This would be the output from your server side (php if thats what your using) - it stores the ID of the image in the `data` attribute

JavaScript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.imglink').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('dialogid')
        .data('image_id', $(this).data('id'))
        .dialog('open');
   })
})
```

the image id from the `data` attribute is then passed to the `data` attribute of the dialog. This attribute can be accessed using `$(this).data('image_id')` form within the dialog then

Comment: I'm assuming you wanted a `"` instead of a `:` at the end of that data attribute